# Remove any characters before "_"

Tags: r, string, tidyverse

How can I remove any characters and digits before "_"; as an example:

```
> char <- c("SRR04_d3_GCTCGGTAAGCACCTCGCCACATA","SRR04_d1_ACTCGGTAAGCACCTCGCCACATA",
+           "JH-HL_GCTCGGTAAGCATGTCGCCACATA","HZ04_d5_GCTCGGTAAGCACCTCGCCACATA")
> c("GCTCGGTAAGCACCTCGCCACATA","ACTCGGTAAGCACCTCGCCACATA",
+           "GCTCGGTAAGCATGTCGCCACATA","GCTCGGTAAGCACCTCGCCACATA")
[1] "GCTCGGTAAGCACCTCGCCACATA" "ACTCGGTAAGCACCTCGCCACATA" "GCTCGGTAAGCATGTCGCCACATA"
[4] "GCTCGGTAAGCACCTCGCCACATA"
```

Can I do this with `str_replace` function from `tidyverse`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may do this with `sub` -

```
sub('.*_', '', char)

#[1] "GCTCGGTAAGCACCTCGCCACATA" "ACTCGGTAAGCACCTCGCCACATA"
#[3] "GCTCGGTAAGCATGTCGCCACATA" "GCTCGGTAAGCACCTCGCCACATA"
```

Or if you prefer `stringr` functions.

```
stringr::str_remove(char, '.*_')
stringr::str_replace(char, '.*_', '')
```

Comment: This removes the _ I'm not 100% sure the OP wanted that. He said before. If he doesn't then the '' in sub or str_replace can be '_'. In the sample data there is a string  of the form "sometext_moretext_lasttext" what does the OP want as the result? moretext_lasttext or just lasttext - check you get what you want/expect

Answer (score 2):

**Base R:**

Or use `strsplit` and `sapply`:

```
> sapply(strsplit(char, '_'), tail, n=1)
[1] "GCTCGGTAAGCACCTCGCCACATA" "ACTCGGTAAGCACCTCGCCACATA" "GCTCGGTAAGCATGTCGCCACATA" "GCTCGGTAAGCACCTCGCCACATA"
>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative way:

```
library(stringr)
str_replace_all(char, ".*_(?=[^:]+$)", "")
```

output:

```
[1] "GCTCGGTAAGCACCTCGCCACATA" "ACTCGGTAAGCACCTCGCCACATA" "GCTCGGTAAGCATGTCGCCACATA"
[4] "GCTCGGTAAGCACCTCGCCACATA"
```

Answer (score 2):

We may use `trimws` from `base R`

```
trimws(char, whitespace = ".*_")
[1] "GCTCGGTAAGCACCTCGCCACATA" "ACTCGGTAAGCACCTCGCCACATA" 
[3] "GCTCGGTAAGCATGTCGCCACATA" "GCTCGGTAAGCACCTCGCCACATA"
```

Answer (score 1):

The package `stringr` can be used to extract all the letters at the end of the string with:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(char, "[[:alpha:]]*$")
# [1] "GCTCGGTAAGCACCTCGCCACATA" "ACTCGGTAAGCACCTCGCCACATA" "GCTCGGTAAGCATGTCGCCACATA"
# [4] "GCTCGGTAAGCACCTCGCCACATA"
```

Answer (score 1):

I would phrase your problem using `gsub` with the pattern `[^\W_]+_`.  This will target one or more alphanumeric characters before an
underscore, any number of times.

```r
char <- c("SRR04_d3_GCTCGGTAAGCACCTCGCCACATA","SRR04_d1_ACTCGGTAAGCACCTCGCCACATA",
      "JH-HL_GCTCGGTAAGCATGTCGCCACATA","HZ04_d5_GCTCGGTAAGCACCTCGCCACATA")
output <- gsub("[^\\W_]+_", "", char)
output

[1] "GCTCGGTAAGCACCTCGCCACATA" "ACTCGGTAAGCACCTCGCCACATA"
[3] "GCTCGGTAAGCATGTCGCCACATA" "GCTCGGTAAGCACCTCGCCACATA"
```